# How to get the details of oracle error messages in sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, message

i am building an extproc library on ***AIX 7.1*** / ***Oracle 19*** .
Unfortunately this library could not be loaded and i just get the following message:

> ORA-06520: PL/SQL: Error loading external library

There is no hint about the cause of this error.

In the internet there are many examples which display much more details about the error like this one:

> ORA-06520: PL/SQL: Error loading external library
> ORA-06522: 0509-022 Cannot load module
> /optimapp/IBM/Infosphere/Optim/dp/bin/libODPPORAUdf.11.3.a(libODPPORAUdf.so.11.3).
> 0509-150 Dependent module libODPPDataCnvLib.11.3.a(libODPPDataCnvLib.so.11.3)
> could not be loaded.
> 0509-022 Cannot load module
> libODPPDataCnvLib.11.3.a(libODPPDataCnvLib.so.11.3).
> 0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
> 0509-022 Cannot load module
> /optimapp/IBM/Infosphere/Optim/dp/bin/libODPPORAUdf.11.3.a(libODPPORAUdf.so.11.3).
> 0509-150 Dependent module
> /optimapp/IBM/Infosphere/Optim/dp/bin/libODPPORAUdf.11.3.a(libODPPORAUdf.so.11.3) could not be loaded.

My question is:
How do I get such a detailed message about the oracle error?
Is there a oracle parameter or is it a setting inside plsql?

Thank you

Comment: Please quote the exactly command you tried when you got this message.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you have three options:

1. Remove the error-handling. If you don't have an `EXCEPTION` section, the full error, including the stack trace will propagate to the caller.
2. Add `raise;` to your error-handling section. As with removing the error handling, calling `raise` as the last line in the `EXCEPTION` section will allow the full error to bubble up to the caller. This allows you to both log the error in the PL/SQL and the caller.
3. Log the stacktrace in the error-handling section. `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE` can be used to get the full stacktrace from errors in PL/SQL. This includes the original error, so if you use this, you don't typically need to log `ERRMSG` as well.